# Prove that the rational numbers are countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> [image]

I see that the hint give me the answer, so if I were to prove the statement I will write the hint but I do not think that the proof is so trivial like this. could anyone show me how he/she will write the proof in terms of this hint please.

Also I have another question from where did $Q_{0}$ come? if $k=0$ we can not divide by 0 in the definition for $Q_{k}$, so may be $Q_{0}$ comes from $j \in \mathbb{N}$, but our union is over k which belongs to $\mathbb{N}$, so k may be equal 0. I got confused, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: is this homework ?

Comment: No I am reading the book and trying to solve by myself @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: Show that $Q_k$ is countable and that the countable union of countable sets is also countable. There might be an easier way.

Comment: *I see that the hint give me the answer, so if I were to prove the statement I will write the hint*.  Can you see that? If so, try to explain, if only informally: what does the hint have to do with the question being asked? In what way does the hint *prove* countability of the rationals?

Comment: It shows $\mathbf Q$, being a countable union of countable sets, is countable.

Comment: @Cornman any typical method that can be called the "easier way" amounts to the proof that $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ is countable, or at least uses this fact.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  my answer to u is as Bernard`s answer.

Comment: @Intuition Well if Bernard's answer is something you could have arrived at on your own (and if it's something covered in class or that you're expected to know), then that's really all you need to say on top of the hint.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I think the "easiest" way is to use Cantor's diagonal argmument, which might not be the most intuitiv method.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elvOZm0d4H0

Comment: @Cornman Again, that's just the usual proof that $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ is countable.  Note also that the "diagonal map" from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Q$ is not a bijection, so some care is required in applying the argument directly (e.g. using Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein).

Comment: @Cornman  showing that $Q_k$ is countable using induction right, if $k = 1$ I will have $\mathbb{Z}$ which is countable . then assume that $Q_k$ is countable and I want to show that $Q_{k +1 }$ is countable , but the last step is why ?

Comment: @Intuition There's no obvious relationship between $Q_k$ and $Q_{k+1},$ so why would you use induction?  It suffices to note that $\Bbb Z$ is countable, and that
$$
f: \Bbb Z \to Q_k\\
f(j) = j/k
$$
is a bijection (for any positive integer $k$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are allowed to use that a countable union of countable sets is countable then things are not so difficult:

Put $A(i)=\{\frac{i}{j}| j \in \mathbb{Z}$ \ $\{0\}\}$ which is a countable set because $\mathbb{Z}$ \ $\{0\}$ is countable.

Thus we have $\mathbb{Q}=\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}A(i)$ which is a countable union of countable sets.

This is not exactly the way your book proposes but its very similar.

I believe you get the idea.

Comment: yes I think so .... thank u :)

Comment: you are welcome..

Comment: I have asked another question in my question, could you please help me in answering it, if you do not mind?

Comment: @Intuition indeed we cannot divide by zero..so in the set i would write $j \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$..maybe the author forgot to mention it

Answer (score 2):

The other answer works but it's not intuitive and the formula given falls from the sky.

The initial idea is correct. That every positive rational number can be put in lowest terms, and that these representations inject into $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ means that all we have to do is show this is countable, and apply the fact that the union of two countable sets is countable (this can be done by weaving together the sets, the same way the odds and evens can be woven together), and then add in $0$.

Here is a more natural map. We will inject $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. Since there is an obvious injection in the reverse direction, the two are bijective by Cantor-Bernstein.

The injection is given by mapping $(a,b) \mapsto 2^a3^b$. Since every such number will be unique (because $2$ and $3$ are prime), this is an injection.

So we have a sequence of injections $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, and an obvious injection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ given by the inclusion, and so again by Cantor-Bernstein, we have a bijection, and so the positive rationals are countable.

To include the negative rationals, use the argument we outlined above. We have shown that the positive rationals are countable. The same argument shows the negative rationals are countable. Now fix an ordering of each of them, so we have what amount to sequences $(a_1, a_2, a_3, ...)$ and $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ where $b_i = -a_i$. Then the sequence $(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, ...)$ will do the job.

Lastly, we need to add $0$. But we know that a countable set union a singleton is still countable. So this completes the proof.

This argument has the nice property that it tells us how to prove that any finite product of countable sets is countable, all we have to do is just use more prime numbers.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Just because something has a name does not make it obvious. If the OP hasn't seen this formula before, probably they have no idea why it works, and are completely baffled about how you found it.

Comment: Thanks for your positive comment. (+1).

Comment: Also @Salahamam_Fatima the O.P wants his exercise to be solved according to the hint  given to him/her from the textbook

Comment: @MariosGretsas my answer takes into account the hint you speak about. Q_1=NxN.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Not exactly because the hint sais to write the rationals as a countable union of countable sets..and your answer is nice but it is not what the O.P wants.

Answer (score 1):

As Omnomnonom said, we just need to prove that $A=\Bbb N\times \Bbb N $ is countable.
for this, consider the map
$$f:(i,j)\mapsto n=\frac {(i+j)(i+j+1)}{2}+j$$

$f $ is a bijection from $A $ to $\Bbb N $.

in fact for $n\in \Bbb N $ there exist a unique $(i,j) $ given by

$$j=n-\frac {d (d+1)}{2} $$
with
$$d=\lfloor \frac {-1+\sqrt {8n+1}}{2} \rfloor $$
and
$$i=d-j $$

such that $f (i,j)=n $

done.

> $f $ is the triangle numbering.

according to this, the members of $A $ are classified as
$$(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(3,0).... $$